# Find at least one solution of system of equations with constraints

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, simplex-method

Consider the system of equations with constraints
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y+z+t+u+v=3(a+b), \\
 x+y+2(z+t)+3u=6b\\
0 \leq x,y,z,t,u,v \leq 1,
\end{cases}
$$
here $0 \leq a,b  \leq 1$ are  fixed  parameters.

I need to find **at least one** non-trivial solution of the equation. Under nontrivial  I mean a solution  that  is   differ from $0$ and $1$, it would be very preferable for almost all $a,b.$
Better if  solutions  were  expresed in terms of $a,b$. If not then  must be an   algorithm to calculate it.

My attempt. I treated the problem as an optimization problem and try to use the simplex method. Unfortunatelly I get very often  a solution with many zeros and ones. For example if $a=0.22,  b=0.34$ I get
$$ t= 0.52,u= 0.0,v= 0.16,x= 1.0,y= 0.0,z= 0.0$$
and it is not so good.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use interior point methods instead of the simplex method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior-point_method

Comment: presumably that they're all between 0 and 1

Comment: $x$ and $y$ seem to be essentially equivalent - couldn't you replace the $x+y$ term with just a $2x$?

Comment: @Moo, all variables between 0 and 1

Comment: @inavda  well, yes.. and then $z+t$ can be replaces with $z$

Comment: @user807138 with crossover disabled, otherwise you end up with a basic solution from the Simplex method.

Answer (score 1):

Adding and subtracting, we obtain the set of all solutions to be:

$y=6a+u-2v-x$ and $z=-3a+3b-t-2u+v$.

So for example setting $a=\frac{1}{2}, u=\frac{1}{6}, v=\frac{6}{7},x=\frac{1}{2}, t=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=\frac{2}{3}$ gives $y=\frac{20}{21}$ and $z=\frac{11}{21}$.

Comment: what about other $a$ and $b$?

Comment: You can alter the values of $a$ and $b$ slightly and change the other values accordingly so that they're between 0 and 1.